# Factor Rings in Commutative Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, suppose that $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$. Suppose that $R/I\cong S_1$ and $R/J\cong S_2$. It is true that if  $S_1\subset S_2$ if then $J\subset I$?

Comment: Technically $R/I$ is never a subset of $R/J$ unless $I=J$.

Comment: To Brian: Considere $R$ the polinomial ring in one variable over the reals. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $p(x)=x-1$ and $J$ the ideal generated by $q(x)=x^2+1$. Then $R/I$ is the real field and $R/J$ is the complex field.

Comment: No, $R/I$ is **isomorphic** to the real field, and $R/J$ is **isomorphic** to the complex field, but $R/I\nsubseteq R/J$.

Comment: Brian, you're right.I have edited the question.

Comment: Even with your changes, it still is problematic. You are choosing an isomorphism...

Comment: If by $S_1 \subset S_2$ you mean $S_1$ embeds in $S_2$ then this is easily seen to be false. Consider $R=k[x,y]$, $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following. Let $k$ be a field. For all $a\in k$, we have
$$k[X]/(X-a)\cong k.$$
However, each ideal $(X-a)$ is maximal, and so none is contained in the other.